# dpkg.pm @INC dpkg-scanpackages / > Packages

Tags: macos, command-line, macports, cydia, fink

I am running Max OS X 10.9

Installed: -Xcode 5 (latest version) -Fink -MacPorts -Xcode Command Line Tools -Theos

I have a shell script running

```
Dpkg-scanpackages debs / > Packages
```

But i am getting this error when running the script

```
Last login: Tue Jul  8 11:43:25 on console
Mayss-iMac:~ Mays$ /Users/Mays/Desktop/Generate_Packages.command ; exit;
Can't locate Dpkg.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /sw/lib/perl5 /sw/lib/perl5/darwin /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/darwin-
thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-
multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at /opt/local/bin/dpkg-scanpackages line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/local/bin/dpkg-scanpackages line 8.
logout
[Process completed]
```

It used to work but when i installed Theos it stopped working and gave that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you out, I had the same issue. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9TOaHp-Gio